# Search results are old/out of date

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

I was trying to do a search for new questions using the advanced search tags such as `is:question` and `intags:mine`. This normally works well, but today it is not showing any questions newer than 2nd June. For example, try this link which should show all questions in my tags, ordered by newest first:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine
```

Has some back-end script stopped running perhaps?

Edit:

Search appears to be out-of-date for all search type (not just advanced search) and across all SE sites.

**Edit**: after working fine for a while, the bug is back in July 30<sup>th</sup> 2014:

> [image]

Comment: It got nothing to do with advanced search, all search results are limited to June 2 or before.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Why are search results limited? And what is advanced search then?

Comment: Search is not running over the live database itself, whatever code/job that is responsible to index the live database has stopped working and the dev team should bring it back to life. It might take hours, or it might take weeks, really can't tell. Advanced search is not relevant to this bug report, because it affects the whole search mechanism that's why I removed the tag.

Comment: Worth to mention this is cross network: all sites in Stack Exchange appear to be affected. Amazing how nobody noticed until now!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Ah I see, should I edit the question or just leave it?

Comment: Might have something to do with the move of servers to the new DC?

Comment: You can edit and state it's out of date for all kinds of search, in all sites, yes. :)

Comment: @rene good call! When did they move?

Comment: @rene: absolutely. The new elacticsearch cluster lost a chunk of new data, by the looks of it. I noticed it on mobile and assumed it was still indexing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Would it take so long to catch up? I assume the search cluster started with a backup of the already indexed data? Or is that not how it works? My bet is on a job that is not running...

Comment: @rene: Yeah, something is b0rken and stuck. IIRC 2nd of June is the date the site was switched to the Oregon center, so this is an old dataset.

Comment: No idea what all happened here, but this appears to be resolved now.

Comment: @Anna it's back in full glory.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Should the `status-completed` tag be removed from this? And what should I do with my new question?

Comment: @DavidG yeah, already flagged asking to remove it. What new question you have? Oh, just noticed, sorry. Think it better be deleted.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I've deleted it

Comment: Reporting bugs again is better than editing/flagging old ones, @ShadowWizard. The latter is much harder for us to track. I'm on it this time, but for future reference...

Comment: @Anna but exact same bug, no answer... anyway think it's better to track it down so it won't happen again - looking forward to see the bug hunted and smacked!

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not sure if this is a bug or an infrastructure-type problem... I'm pinging the relevant folks on this.

Comment: @Anna thanks, Oded mentioned in chat it's likely a broken elastic search index then said he's pinging relevant folks too, and shortly afterwards it worked again. So, guess someone somewhere might have some info on this already. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a problem with search indexing that caused this issue.

A recycle of the elastic search nodes sorted it out.

Thanks for reporting!

Comment: Thanks, if this happens again, what is the ideal course of action? Comment here or post whole new report which will be exact dupe?

Comment: @ShadowWizard - these are all separate occurrences, so I'd rather see a new report than a reopening of an existing one.